# Why aren't md-menu options injected in my hybrid Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material

I am trying to debug an error I am receiving in my hybrid Angular/AngularJS application on reloading. You can see an example of this at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-angular-upgrade-di-error?embed=1&file=app/layout.component.html). This method of bootstrapping AngularJS in an Angular app is [based on Victor Savkin work](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngupgrade-like-a-pro-lazy-loading-angularjs-applications-469819f5c86).

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'xPosition' of undefined
>     at new MatMenu (VM4642 material.umd.js:13096)
>     at createClass (VM4479 core.umd.js:10963)
>     at createDirectiveInstance (VM4479 core.umd.js:10788)
>     at createViewNodes (VM4479 core.umd.js:12229)
>     at callViewAction (VM4479 core.umd.js:12675)
>     at execComponentViewsAction (VM4479 core.umd.js:12584)
>     at createViewNodes (VM4479 core.umd.js:12256)
>     at createRootView (VM4479 core.umd.js:12124)
>     at callWithDebugContext (VM4479 core.umd.js:13507)
>     at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (VM4479 core.umd.js:12824) "<my-layout class="ng-scope" ng-version="4.3.6">"
> ```

By stepping through the code I can see that object that `xPosition` is on is an [injected default options object](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9673f63c11a286639e5d3a3b9e379392fd666d2a/src/lib/menu/menu-directive.ts#L150). The `MdMenu` depends on this default options object that is referenced via an InjectionToken. However in my hybrid Angular/AngularJS application, this dependency is coming back undefined when reloading the page. If switching to that page from another page, the dependency loads correctly.

Below is a simplified view of the dom structure. Note that ng1 and ng2 components are interlaced. The above error refers to the top downgraded component rather than the downgraded component that wraps the `<md-menu>`.

```html
<ng2-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div ui-view>
    <downgraded-ng2-component>
      <ng1-component>
        <another-downgraded-ng2-component>
          <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]"toolbarMenu"></button>
          <md-menu #toolbarMenu="mdMenu">
            <button md-menu-item>...</button>
          </md-menu>
        </another-downgraded-ng2-component>
      </ng1-component>
    </downgraded-ng2-component>
  </div>
</ng2-root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that there is no guarantee that the providers of one module will be instantiated before the providers of another module, unless there is something that explicitly designates to Angular that they are needed.

In your case, for example, `AngularJSModule` (whose constructor bootstraps the AngularJS part of the app) transitively depends on `MatMenu`'s `MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` injectable. But Angular doesn't realize that (since it is hidden away inside the AngularJS bootstrapping).

For example, if you would explicitly declare a dependnecy on `MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` from `AngularJSModule`, everything should work:

```
export class AngularJSModule {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) ignored: object, upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Note: This is just for illustration purposes. I don't actually recommend doing this.**

---

Although this approach of lazy-bootstrapping AngularJS is not exactly "officially supported", you should be able to make it work easily, by ensuring that bootstrapping AngularJS happens asynchronously (giving time to all providers - including `MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` - to be initialized). There are several ways to achieve this. Here are a couple of examples:

1. Call `upgrade.bootstrap()` asynchronously from `AngularJSModule`'s constructor:

   ```
   export class AngularJSModule {
     constructor(upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
       Promise.resolve().then(() => {
         // Bootstrap AngularJS
         // ...
       });
     }
   }
   ```

   [Updated demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-angular-upgrade-di-error-nfouf2?file=app%2Fangularjs.module.ts)
2. Call `upgrade.bootstrap()` from the `EmptyComponent`'s `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook. In this case, we need to make sure this is only called once, because `EmptyComponent` could be instantiated many times:

   ```
   let angularJsBootstrapped = false;

   @Component({template: ''})
   export class EmptyComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       // Ensure AngularJS is only bootstrapped once.
       if (!angularJsBootstrapped) {
         this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [module.name]);
         setUpLocationSync(this.upgrade);

         angularJsBootstrapped = true;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   [Updated demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-angular-upgrade-di-error-ggyd7n?file=app/angularjs.module.ts)

---

Finally, note that normally we recommend calling `upgrade.bootstrap()` in the main `NgModule`'s `ngDoBootstrap()` method,. But since it is not called for modules that are lazy-loaded by the `Router` (because they are technically not bootstrapped), you need to resort to one of the methods shown above.